# Moving html list from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations, keyframe

so I have this html code. I'm trying to do moving list, I'm new to animations and I can't find any tips how to do it. I would like to start from that: we have all 6 list items visible inside div, and they change positions, first item1 wil be at item6 place, item2 will be at item1 place etc. Moving from bottom to top, and after change position stops for 3 seconds. They should change positions indefinitely, from bottom to top. Anyone can help me with that?

```
 <div class="moving_list">
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
        <li>item6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you would like to do javascript to perform your desired action. instead of creating the list in HTML you should look into creating the list with js.